# Password entered is visible and not hidden

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grails

This is my password field in grails. Everything works fine but the length of the field is very long.

```
<g:passwordField  required="" name='j_password'

id='password' value="${u?.password}"

class="form-control input-lg" type="text" id="inputLarge"

value="" placeholder="Password" />
```

Therefore i tried another approach. I used `<g:textField` instead. The length issue was sorted but the password entered can be seen and its not hidden.

```
<g:textField type="password" required="" name='j_password'

id='password' value="${u?.password}"

class="form-control input-lg" type="text" id="inputLarge"

value="" placeholder="Password" />
```

Comment: You can use `<g:passwordField` and add the desired width as attribute  `<g:passwordField style="width:(yourwidth)px" ........ />`

Comment: It might not be responsive if so.

Comment: Then use a percentage value instead pixel value

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<input type="password" class="input-mini" name='j_password' id='password' value="hello">
```

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware with grails but try to change type="password", Hope it works and resolve problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<g:field type="password" name="password" value="${userInstance?.password}"  size='15'/>
```

Length of the field issue is solved with option Size-Specifies the width in characters of the field. Here size='15' is number of characters in the field.